# PL/SQL LOGOFF TRIGGER does not capture logoff event properly

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I created a LOGOFF trigger like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER logoffTrigger  
BEFORE LOGOFF ON DATABASE  
BEGIN  
INSERT INTO logoffAudit("type","user")VALUES('LOGOFF',USER);  
END;  
/
```

and tested it with a small VB.Net application that uses the OracleConnection object of the Oracle.DataAccess.Client module. While the LOGON event is captured properly by a similar LOGON trigger, the LOGOFF event is only captured when the client connection is closed and the entire client application is closed afterwards, i.e. this is not enough:

```
cn.Close()
```

nor is this:

```
cn.Close()  
cn.Dispose()
```

nor this:

```
cn.Close()  
cn.Dispose()  
cn = Nothing
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance,
Jan

Comment: why not use `AUDIT` ?

Comment: I want to perform some actions upon the events, therefore I cannot use AUDIT.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using connection pooling in your application?  In the *vast* majority of three-tier applications, you would maintain a connection pool in the middle tier so that users don't have to wait on every page for a connection to the database to be opened and closed again.  When the application opens a connection, it gets an existing connection from the pool (assuming there is a free connection) and when the application closes a connection, it returns the connection to the pool.  While that is radically more efficient in terms of performance, using a connection pool means that you're divorcing application sessions from database sessions so logon and logoff triggers won't necessarily capture application logon or logoff actions.

In your case, my wager is that the logon trigger appears to work only because the connection pool is empty when the application starts up.  If you log on and off repeatedly, I'd wager that not all the application logons would cause the logon trigger to fire.